# Trying to get the value and text of list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have multiple list items with value attributes that contain Urls. I'm trying to capture the Url and Text of each list item within a contain on click event. Nothing happens when I click on a list item.

```
<ul id="expList" class="list">
<li value="https://hosted.demo.ca" class="collapsed expanded">Sharepoint Demo Website</ul>
<li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic" class="collapsed active">Academic
<ul style="display: none;"><li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/bm">Board Meetings</li><li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/cmtte">Committee</li>
<li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/dm">Document Management</li>
<li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/pm">Project Management</li>
</ul>
```

JsFiddle with full HTML if that helps http://jsfiddle.net/6yXV6/

My code:

```
site = $('#expList');
site.on('click','li',function(){
  siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
  siteName = $(this).text();
  console.log(siteUrl);
  console.log(siteName);
  RefreshSiteLists();
});
```

I've used this code to make this list expand and collapse, could it be conflicting somehow:

```
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click( function(event) {
      if (this == event.target) {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
      }
      return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed').children('ul').hide();

        //Create the button functionality
    $('#expandList').unbind('click').click( function() {
        $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
    });
    $('#collapseList').unbind('click').click( function() {
        $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
    });
  };

$(function() {
   $("#expList li").click(function() {
      // remove classes from all
      $("li").removeClass("active");
      // add class to the one we clicked
      $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

EDIT: I think most of you have answered my question and that there's something else in my code that's preventing it from running. So once I narrow that down I'll probably post another question related to that.

Comment: What exactly is the problem "Bruce Wayne"? ;)

Comment: Nothing is happening when I click on an list item

Comment: Did you check the browser's console? Press F12 and then you will see the console.

Comment: yea, nothing showed up. I put in an alert so I can't miss it but it doesn't run either.

Comment: Can you please check the fiddle which I gave in my answer?

Comment: The [*value*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) attribute of an LI is supposed to be an integer that is its index within an **ordered** list. If you want access to some other value, please use an appropriate attribute.

Comment: what would be an appropriate attribute to store urls in a list item

Comment: Your problem statement and title doesnt conform each other. Please make it clear.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. I have list items and I need to get the value and text when clicked. How is that different from my statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, this will get the this list item that you click on and show you the value and text within that list.

```
$("li").click(function(){
    if(this.id != 'myList')
    {
        siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
        siteName = $(this).text();
        console.log(siteUrl);
        console.log(siteName);
    }

    else
    {
        siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
        siteName = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
        console.log(siteUrl);
        console.log(siteName);
    }
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo (using console.log)](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/5p79Z/11/)

[jsFiddle Demo (using alert)](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/8tjXH/)

Comment: I tried the fiddle the console returns this error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alert' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: I removed the refreshsitelist() since that was causing an error. But the siteUrl keeps only returning the top site and the siteName returns all sites at once.

Comment: According to the code, you asked for the value of the list item clicked. So it's returning the specific value of the clicked list item. But you are asking for the text that is within that list item which has all the names that are displayed within it. So you are getting all the names and only the value of that particular list item.

Comment: How would I get the value and text of the individual items clicked and not all of them.

Comment: Check the updated solution. This gets the list item value and innerText individually.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is with your **`html`**.  Better validate it properly.

1) Improper tag closed

```
<li value="https://hosted.demo.ca" class="collapsed expanded">Sharepoint Demo Website</ul>
<li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic" class="collapsed active">Academic
...........
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnYxN/3/)

Answer (score 0):

your problem, in short, is that `$(this)` is having two context entries when an `li` is clicked, that's because of nesting `li` inside another, you can see that if you do a `console.log($(this))`, so the solution is adding an event stopper: `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` to stop this from happening and the code will be like this:

```
 site = $('#expList');
  site.on('click','li',function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
  siteName = $(this)[0].childNodes[0];
  console.log(siteUrl);
  console.log(siteName);
});
```

and by the way, it's like @user1671639 sayed, there is a problem in the html closing tags, it should be:

```
    <ul id="expList" class="list">
      <li value="https://hosted.demo.ca" class="collapsed expanded">
        Sharepoint Demo Website
        <ul id='#internal' style="display: block;">
          <li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic" class="collapsed active">
            Academic
          </li>
          <li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/bm">Board Meetings</li>
          <li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/cmtte">Committee</li>
          <li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/dm">Document Management</li>
          <li value="https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/pm">Project Management</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: I'll try this, but yea I didn't copy the HTML probably because it was too big. The closing tags are correct however. I can post a JSFiddle with the entire html output if needed.

Comment: Yea I tried but it didn't help. I posted a JSFiddle with more info

Comment: just check it in here, http://jsfiddle.net/labibismaiel/3ggAQ/

Comment: Click on the first name "Demo" and you'll get all the list items and not just demo

Comment: @Batman Again you're missing the point.  check my answer.

Comment: Hey, I think there's something stopping it from running. When I click on it nothing at all happens. No error, no console log, no alert, just nothing.